# how can ADO pointer uses the two member access operators . and ->?

Tags: c++, ado

I am new to programming database in c++ using ADO. I did some application and it was ok. the thing that matters me:

I know that pointer to an object use `->` to access members and an object uses `.` to access them:

in ADO how _ConnectionPtr uses the two: `.` and `->` to access members.
I searched to much but I didn't get a satisfying answer. 
any help is appreciated.

```
_ConnectionPtr pConnection;
pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection)); // 1 using `.`
pConnection->Open(...); // 2 using `->`
```

Comment: They are probably overloaded in the `_ConnectionPtr` class.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I really want to know how with an example

Comment: See the last section in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719).